# Transformation of Discrete Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am having trouble figuring out what values y takes in the below problem:

Let $f(x)$ be the PDF of $x$, For each of the following, find the PDF of Y:

$f(x)= 1/4$ when $x$ is between $0$ and $1$,
$f(x)= 3/8$ when $x$ is between $3$ and $5$,
$f(x)=0$ otherwise

Y=1/x

I am guessing that f(y)= 3/8y when y is between 3 and 5 but am otherwise clueless

Answer (score 1):

We have $Pr(X \le x) =\begin{cases} \frac{x}{4} &, 0 < x< 1 \\ \frac14+\frac38(x-3) &, 3< x <5\end{cases}$

$$Pr(Y \le y)=Pr(\frac1X \le y)=Pr(X \ge \frac1y)$$

That is if $1 < y$, we have $Pr(Y  \le y)=Pr(X \ge \frac1y)=1-\frac{1}{4y}$

and if $\frac15 < y <\frac13$, we have $Pr(Y \le y)=Pr(X \ge \frac1y)=\frac34-\frac{3}{8}(\frac1y-3)$

Differentiating each rule, we have

$$f_Y(y)=\begin{cases} \frac1{4y^2} &, 1<y \\ \frac3{8y^2}  & ,\frac15< y < \frac13\\ 0 &\text{, Otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that your random variable $X$ is not discrete random variable.

One way you can compute it is:

1. Find CDF of $X$
2. Then CDF of $Y$ is $G(y) = P(Y < y) = P(X>1/y ) = 1 - F(1/y)$
3. Then PDF of $Y$ is derivative of the CDF.